# Jmeter -session id capturing issue

Tags: jmeter

I am currently doing a performance testing using Jmeter

Session id is generated correctly and get captured in the cookie data but the same session id is not displayed along with the url

For example it displays as mentioned

> https://qa-mtp.xxxxxx.com:8443/RA/search?param_1=1&param_2=S_TREE&param_3=LNA0&_=1485153087241&JSESSIONID=
>   GET data:
>
> Cookie Data: $Version=0; JSESSIONID=A0C47D6F8D5EE2C982A27A986ED08CD8;
>   $Path=/RA

I have added HTP URL Rewriting modifier,JSON path extractor also but could not resolve the issue.

Please help me out to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be worked around using [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager). It is possible to  "tell" JMeter to store the cookies in [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

- Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

  ```
  CookieManager.save.cookies=true
  ```
- Restart JMeter to pick the amended property up
- Change your URL Path to look like:

  > /RA/search?param_1=1&param_2=S_TREE&param_3=LNA0&_=1485153087241&JSESSIONID=**${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}**
- JMeter will substitute the variable with the actual cookie value in the runtime

See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) article for more detailed explanation on aspects of managing cookies in JMeter tests.